# Creating an array2D class crashing when compiling

Tags: c++, memory

my homework assignment is asking me to create a array2d class and I am having trouble compiling it. It crashes every time it is compiled and I am unsure what I am doing wrong. My debugger is saying it is during my set value portion but I am not sure what it is exactly. Help would be great!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class array2D {
private:
    int xRes, yRes;
    float **xtable;
public:
    array2D(int xRes, int yRes){
        float **xtable;
        xtable = new float*[yRes];
            for(int i=0;i < yRes;i++) {
                xtable[i] = new float[xRes];}}
    ~array2D(){
        for (int i = 0; i<yRes; i++){
            delete [] xtable[i];}
        delete [] xtable;}
    void getSize(int &xRes, int &yRes){}
    int getValue (int x, int y){return xtable[x][y];}
    void setValue(int x, int y, int Val) {xtable[x][y]=Val;}
};

int main() {
    array2D *a = new array2D(320,240);
    int xRes, yRes;
    a->getSize(xRes,yRes);
    for(int i=0;i < yRes;i++){
        for(int j=0;j < xRes;j++){
            a->setValue(i,j,100); // constant value of 100 at all locations
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i < yRes;i++){
       for(int j=0;j < xRes;j++){
           cout << a->getValue(i,j) << " ";
       }
       cout << endl;
    }
    delete a;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `void getSize(int &xRes, int &yRes){}` need to be `void getSize(int &xRes, int &yRes){ xRes = this.xRes; yRes = this.yRes;}`? And indent your code properly so that it is more readable.

Comment: sorry about the indentation, will keep that in mind. This was my first post. I am not sure by what you mean by this.xRes since I didn't make an object yet.

Comment: You mean the compilation fails, not that the compiler crashed.

Answer (score 3):

In these lines

```
array2D(int xRes, int yRes){
    float **xtable;
```

you are declaring a local variable. The class member variable of the same name remains uninitialized and you use that later.

Remove the second line.

Also, the member variables `xRes` and `yRes` are not initialized either.

Use:

```
array2D(int xResIn, int yResIn) : xRes(xResIn), yRes(yResIn) {
   xtable = new float*[yRes];
   for(int i=0;i < yRes;i++) {
      xtable[i] = new float[xRes];
   }
}
```

Also, change

```
void getSize(int &xRes, int &yRes){}
```

to

```
void getSize(int &xResOut, int &yResOut)
{
   xResOut = this->xRes;
   yResOut = this->yRes;
}
```

As you expand this class, keep in mind [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and implement the copy constructor and copy assignment operator.

```
array2D(array2D const& copy) { ... }
array2D& operator=(array2D const& rhs) { ... }
```

Comment: When I remove that line, it says that float **xtable is a private member, which makes sense. Should I have an initization step somewhere before I start anything?

Comment: @digon1631, that doesn't make sense. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: It actually is compiling now but crashing when it runs. My compiler is GNU GCC Compiler.

Comment: Ahh I see it now. It compiles and works. I just failed to initialize the variables. Thanks!

Comment: what does the "this-->xRes" portion mean? I understand that it is pointing to soemthing, but why use the word this?

Comment: @digon1631, It's another syntax for accessing members of the current object. You may use `xResOut = xRes;` also.